# Java strange behaviour when using double division in declaration/init

Tags: java, floating-point, initialization, declaration, division

I have tested these two codes:

1)

```
double b = 1 / 2;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Result: 0.0

2)

```
double b = 0.5;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Result: 0.5

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `double b = 1 / 2;` first computes `1 / 2`, which is simple integer division and evaluates to 0, and then casts that value to the double `0.0` to assign it to `b`.